# Smooth slider dragging through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following code. It simply loop through and Object and display the object key in HTML as sliding bar.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
   $('#threshold').change(updateThreshold);
   function updateThreshold () {
       var thresholdIndex = parseInt($('#threshold').val(), 10);
       $("#foldchange_threshold").html(foldchange_thresholds[thresholdIndex]);
   };

   var foldchange_thresholds = [];
    var mydata = {"3":["c","d"], 
                  "3.5":["j","k"], 
                  "1.5":["a","b"], 
                  "0.5":["c","d"], 
                  "2.0":["e","f"], 
                  "2.5":["x","y"] };
    
    Object.keys(mydata).sort().forEach(function(key) {
      foldchange_thresholds.push(key);
      
      });
      
    $('#threshold').attr('max', foldchange_thresholds.length-1);

  
   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
    <!-- Display the sliding bar -->
    <input id="threshold" type="range"  min="0" max="1" step="1" value="0" />
    <br>

    <!-- Show foldchange threshold -->
    <div id="foldchange_threshold" style="display: inline-block; align:center;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

As you notice upon the script execution. The sliding process is lagging, it stop for a while after dragging. How can I smoothen the dragging process?

Comment: It's smooth in my browser. It just moves in steps. No lag as such.

Comment: No lag for me either. Moves in steps like you designed it to

Comment: @forgivenson: Is there other alternatives than moving in steps? I mean smoother than steps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it will fix anything, but you could make it more efficient by not making jquery find the elements every time...

```
var $foldchange = $("#foldchange_threshold");
$('#threshold').change(function() {
  var thresholdIndex = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  $foldchange.html(foldchange_thresholds[thresholdIndex]);
});
```

---

**Update** as requested by the OP...

```js
$(function() {
  var foldchange_thresholds = [];
  var mydata = {"3":["c","d"], 
                "3.5":["j","k"], 
                "1.5":["a","b"], 
                "0.5":["c","d"], 
                "2.0":["e","f"], 
                "2.5":["x","y"] };
    
  Object.keys(mydata).sort().forEach(function(key) {
    foldchange_thresholds.push(key);
  });

  var $foldchange = $("#foldchange_threshold");
  $('#threshold').change(function() {
    var thresholdIndex = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    $foldchange.html(foldchange_thresholds[thresholdIndex]);
  }).attr('max', foldchange_thresholds.length-1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
    <!-- Display the sliding bar -->
    <input id="threshold" type="range"  min="0" max="1" step="1" value="0" />
    <br>

    <!-- Show foldchange threshold -->
    <div id="foldchange_threshold" style="display: inline-block; align:center;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give running example? e.g. through [**StackSnippet**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Not sure why that is necessary?  The problem with snippets is that it requires me to replicate the entire code, which makes it more difficult to see exactly what's changed.  Isn't my example above enough for you?